# Scope of methods of an anonymous object - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin if I define a method on an anonymous object, sometimes I am able to access it, while other times I am not. This seems to have something to do with scoping rules, but I am not sure what.

In the code example below, the access to `example3.field.method()` will cause a compilation error. Interestingly, `example2.field.method()` compiles just fine.

What could be the explanation for the below behaviour?

```
class Example3 {
    val field = object {
        fun method() {}
    }
}

fun showcase() {
    val example1 = object {
        fun method() {}
    }
    example1.method()
    println(example1::class.qualifiedName)

    class Example2 {
        val field = object {
            fun method() {}
        }
    }

    val example2 = Example2()
    example2.field.method()
    println(example2::class.qualifiedName)

    val example3 = Example3()
    // example3.field.method()  // won't compile
    println(example3::class.qualifiedName)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From docs [Object Expressions and Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html):

> Note that anonymous objects can be used as types only in local and
>   private declarations. If you use an anonymous object as a return type
>   of a public function or the type of a public property, the actual type
>   of that function or property will be the declared supertype of the
>   anonymous object, or `Any` if you didn't declare any supertype. **Members
>   added in the anonymous object will not be accessible.**

Demonstrated in code sample below:

```
class Example4{
    val publicObj = object{
        val x = 1
    }

    private val privateObj = object{
        val x = 2
    }

    fun showcase(){
        val scopedObj = object{
            val x = 3
        }
        println(publicObj.x)    // ERROR : unresolved reference: x
        println(privateObj.x)   // OK
        println(scopedObj.x)    // OK
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to use anonymous objects in a proper way, but could anyone give some explanation behind this(accessibility difference)? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pawel gave the correct answer to your question, pointing to the documentation:

> the actual type of that function or property will be the declared supertype of the anonymous object, or Any if you didn't declare any supertype.

But just adding that if you really need to access `example3.field.method()` you could declare a supertype to `field` in `Example3`:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun method()
}

class Example3 {
    val field = object: MyInterface { 
        override fun method() {} 
    }
}

fun main() {
    val example3 = Example3()
    example3.field.method()
}
```